# How to use System.nanoTime() for sequencing events with more precision

Tags: java, time

I want to attach a timestamp whenever an event happens in my application. Let's assume that a client creates a Event object and I want to attach a creation timestamp to the Event object. I can do this using the System.currentTimeMillis() within the constructor.  This works fine if the Event objects are created no faster than once every millisecond. In this case each Event object gets a different value from System.currentTimeMillis() and hence the Event objects are sequenced.

However if the Event objects need to be created a rate that is faster than one object per millisecond, then my logic breaks. Depending on the rate of object creation 2 or more Event objects end up having the same creation timestamp (since System.currentTimeMillis returned the same value when called in quick succession)

Now how do I sequence the Event objects in this case? I am aware of the System.nanoTime() but that's not related to the epoch.

I am open to storing the creation timestamp within the Event class split into 2 instance variables - creationTimeInMS (long) and creationTimeInNS (long)

I do not want to java.sql.Timestamp which does support nano second precision

Is there anyway I could leverage the System.nanoTime to provide sequencing of the event objects?

Note - It is guaranteed that the event will not get created faster than 1 per nanosecond. Hence nanosecond precision will suffice

The code that I have using is as below

```
class Event {
private long timestamp

public Event() {
...
timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
}
```

So if the Event constructor is called by multiple threads at a rate faster than 1 per millisecond, then two (or more) Event objects get the same timestamp.

The System.nanoTime() is supposed to return unique number if called no faster than once every nano second. However I am not sure how I could use this number in conjunction with the timestamp. Do I add this to the timestamp to generate a nano second precision time?

Comment: Are all of the events handled/created in a single thread? If so, a simple incremental counter (possibly in addition to a ms timestamp) would be sufficient. This won't help if you're actually interested in the precise time between event, but only care about their ordering.

Comment: Extending @JoachimSauer s answer: even if you use a multithreaded approach, you could use an `AtomicLong` as a counter. As for your question: "Is there anyway I could leverage the System.nanoTime to provide sequencing of the event objects?" This I do not understand. If it is guaranteed that events are not created faster than 1 every ns, why does the timestamp (in ns) not suffice to sequence the objects? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Turing85: True, AtomicLong is a very good solution, even if multithreaded. The problem with nanoTime is that it's not guaranteed to be monotonically increasing (specifically it can and will overflow). So it's usually good to measure timespans (provided they are small enough), but not sufficient to order elements with timestamps.

Comment: @ JoachimSauer, the events are created from multiple threads

Comment: @Turing85, added some notes to my original edit

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to achieve that with relying on the wall clock, times are gonna collide and nano second resolution is hard to achieve in practice, a quick solution is to add a wrapper around the time that remembers its last value. This **wont** work in a distributed environment of course.

```
static class MonotonicClock{
    private long last;
    public MonotonicClock(){
        last = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    public synchronized long getNext(){
      long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
      if(last < current){ // last seen is less than "now"
        last = current;
      }else{
         last++; //collision, overclock the time
      }
      return last;
    }
}
```

In a distributed system, things are more complicated. You might need to look at [Lamport timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport_timestamps) and [Vector Clocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_clock) for that.